# Axios request on button click

Tags: reactjs, axios

Why doesn't this function delete the quiz from the database, when it does work with Postman?

```
 deleteQuiz = () => {
    const quiz = this.state.quizData._id
     axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/${quiz}`) 
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)

  })
```

with an onClick:

```
<button onClick={() => this.deleteQuiz(this.state.quizData._id)}>Delete Quiz </button>
```

Similarly, this doesn't work:

```
topicSearch = topic => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/search/${topic}`)
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            this.setState({
                quizSelection: data
            })
        })
     }
}
```

with an onClick within a child component passing in topicSearch

```
 onClick={this.props.topicSearch}
```

But DOES work when calling topicSearch() inside the onChangeHandler and passing in the e.target.value

```
handleTopicChange = eventValue => {
    this.topicSearch(eventValue)
    this.setState({
        topic: topic
    })
}
```

From other examples it seems that passing state into functions is acceptable - is this something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any parameters here:

```js
deleteQuiz = () => {
  const quiz = this.state.quizData._id;
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/${quiz}`).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

So use a parameter like this:

```js
deleteQuiz = quiz => {
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/${quiz}`).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

And this will use the parameter passed and not the one from state.

```js
<button onClick={() => this.deleteQuiz(this.state.quizData._id)}> Delete Quiz </button>
```

Comment: @MdC Can you make a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-dust-72ys7 - it doesn't make the request, but that is the gist

Comment: @MdC Thank you. Will have a quick look.

Comment: @MdC https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-monad-rc704 I have updated the code. What's the problem now.

Comment: The issue was not having set const cors = require('cors'), app.use(cors()) - but thanks for your help :)